# <input type="text">で「複数行表示」&「入力欄のサイズ変更可」対応させることは出来ますか？

Tags: html

**`<input type="text">`で下記実装は可能ですか？**

- 複数行表示対応
  ブラウザ上の見た目は`<textarea>`のような表示だけれども、HTMLタグは`<input type="text">`にしたい、という意味です
- 入力欄のサイズ変更可対応
  `<textarea>`右下にあるような入力欄のサイズ変更機能の追加

Comment: textarea を使わない理由は何かありますか？

Comment: 複数の<input type="text">で並び替え等の処理を行っている関係で、入力項目をく<input type="text">に統一したい、という理由です

Answer (score 2, accepted):

複数行のテキストに `input` 要素を使用することはネイティブでは不可能です<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#text-(type%3Dtext)-state-and-search-state-(type%3Dsearch))</sup>。

> #### § 4.10.5.1.2 Text (type=text) state and Search state (type=search)<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#text-(type%3Dtext)-state-and-search-state-(type%3Dsearch))</sup>
>
> The input element represents a **one line** plain text edit control for the element's value.

`textarea` 要素を使用すると良いと思います。

> #### § 4.10.11 The textarea element<sup>[[2]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element)</sup>
>
> The textarea element represents a **multiline plain text** edit control for the element's raw value. The contents of the control represent the control's default value.

Comment: HTML仕様でここまで定義されているのですね。規定に従い、textarea 要素 を使用することにします